# Tile loading progress for vector sources utilizing tile loading strategy

Tags: openlayers-3

I am loading features into [Vector source](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html) utilizing the [Tile strategy](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.loadingstrategy.html). I'd like implement kind of progress bar, similar to http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/tile-load-events.html.
However, unlike [VectorTile source](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.VectorTile.html), the Vector source doesn't trigger tile loading events which could be used for calculating desired ratio 100*(tilesLoaded/tilesToLoad).

So far I can retrieve the total count of tiles to load, but **I am unable to count already loaded tiles**. The most promising is a custom loader, but it is not clear to me how to modify it without touching the original OL source code.

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
   loader: ol.featureloader.xhrX(url, format),
   strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(tileGrid)
});

// forked method, but the inner 'loadFeaturesXhr' method seems to be private and cannot be used
ol.featureloader.xhrX = function(url, format) {
   /*
      return ol.featureloader.loadFeaturesXhr(url, format,
         function(features, dataProjection) {
            this.addFeatures(features);
            // when tile loading succeeds
            tilesLoaded++;
         },
         function() {
            // when tile loading fails
            tilesLoaded++;
         });
   */
   // just returning the original loader
   return ol.featureloader.xhr(url, format);
}

var url = function(extent, resolution) {
   tilesToLoad++; // when a new tile is needed, this counter is incremented
   var tileCoord = tileGrid.getTileCoordForCoordAndResolution(ol.extent.getCenter(extent), resolution);
   return 'tiles/' +
      tileCoord[0] + '/' +
      tileCoord[1] + '/' +
      (Math.pow(2, tileCoord[0]) + tileCoord[2]) + '.json';
}

var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON({
   defaultDataProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
});
```

Any idea how to call loadFeaturesXhr() method from my source?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of forking default OL3 loader I created a custom one. It was not as hard as expected. Now I can freely add counters to proper places (in the code below I actually update the progress component itself):

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({

   loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {

      var getUrl = function(extent, resolution) {
         progress.addLoading();
         ...
      };

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhr.open('GET', getUrl(extent, resolution), true);
      xhr.onload = function(event) {
         ...
         progress.addLoaded();

      }.bind(this);

      xhr.onerror = function(event) {
         progress.addLoaded();
      }

      xhr.send();
   },
   strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(tileGrid)
});
```